# Send multi-measure record from AWS IOT Core rule to Amazon Timestream

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-iot, aws-iot-core, amazon-timestream

I have an IOT Device sending temperature, humidity and pressure to AWS IOT Core and, with a rule, send it to an Amazon Timestream DB, using the following SQL statement in the IOT Core rule:

```
SELECT temperature, humidity, pressure FROM 'devicepub/data/#'
```

At the moment, I have one record per measure.

However I want to use the new feature of Timeseries, which allows multi-measure records and, therefore, obtain one record per timestamp, which includes all the variables measured.

**How should I write the IOT Core rule?**

**Is it actually possible to do that now?**

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not terribly mistaken, I'm afraid you can't do that yet. Since multi-measure records are fairly new, the timestream action on IoT Core rules doesn't support it yet. The way I see it, you have these options

- Use a lambda to insert multi-measure records into timestream
- Add the measures in the dimension (cheeky, I know)

Answer (score 1):

I tried packing all the required fields and it saved the complete JSON payload as `varchar`.

Example:

```
{
  "data" : {
              "temperature" : 25,
              "humidity: : 30
           }
}
```

Comment: It's columnar format of data (saves as Json string), but multi-measure record is efficient for accessing specific attributes through query.